Is there a git option to show the parent line of a source code when merge conflict occurred?
Is there a git option to show the parent line of a source code when merge conflict occurred?
I want to see the line like == line below:
==  value       = aws_instance.www[*].public_ip
-   value       = coalescelist(aws_instance.www[*].public_ip, ["None"])
 -  value       = aws_instance.client_node[*].public_ip
++  value       = coalescelist(aws_instance.client_node[*].public_ip, ["None"])


You can do a 3-way diff by running git mergetool <file>
You can set mergetool in the git config to you favorite diff tool (meld, bc, diffuse, or whatever)

Yes, I know about 3way. But I want to see the parent line in this format too. Thanks.
